# numpy np.subtract with where clause giving different results for same numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I noticed some odd behavior with `np.subtract`.

My actual situation is more complicated by I replicated something similar with an example array. My python version is 3.8.5.

```
# create a 3x3 array of random integers 
a = np.random.randint(5, size=(3, 3))

#use np.subtract() to subtract 1 using where clause a != 0

np.subtract(a, 1, where=a!= 0)
```

For each successive invocation of `np.subtract(a,1 where=a!=0)` you get different results in the location where the where clause is False. Am I using the where clause inappropriately or is there something buggy going on here?

Sample:

```
a = np.array([[0, 4, 3],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [4, 0, 3]])

np.subtract(a, 1, where=a!= 0)
```

Results:

```
array([[1152921504606846976,                   3,                   2],
       [                  1,                   1,                   1],
       [                  3, 4616189618054758400,                   2]])
```

...

```
array([[1152921504606846976,                   3,                   2],
       [                  1,                   1,                   1],
       [                  3, 8387229874590130729,                   2]])
```

What I *want* is for the result to copy over what was in a in the elements where the where clause is False. So they should be 0 in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an element of the `where` mask is False, the ufunc is not computed for that element. Nothing is written to the output for such elements. That means the output element is whatever happened to already be there, and in this case, that's uninitialized garbage. Quoting the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#optional-keyword-arguments) for the ufunc `where` argument:

> Note that if an uninitialized return array is created, values of False will leave those values **uninitialized**.

If you want to copy values from `a` for false mask elements, then you can initialize the output array as a copy of `a`:

```
result = numpy.subtract(a, 1, where=a!=0, out=a.copy())
```

or, since the values you're copying from `a` are all 0,

```
result = numpy.subtract(a, 1, where=a!=0, out=numpy.zeros_like(a))
```

or use `numpy.where` (which is a completely different thing) to choose elements from either `a` or `a-1`:

```
result = numpy.where(a==0, a, a-1)
```

Comment: @codingknob: But "do nothing" means "leave the old contents of the output array there", not "copy values from `a` there". Did you want to copy values from `a`? Or did you want this to be an in-place operation on `a`? Or did you expect the output to be zeroed first?

Comment: Sorry, should I had a typo and I wasn't clear. Yes I want to copy values from a into the result in the locations where the where clause is False. So the 0 should be copied into the result. Does that make sense?

Comment: @codingknob: Answer expanded.